# How can reference my model in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am trying access my model in my blade template. So I can loop thorough data.

I have tried calling global function like

```
{{ Auth::user }}
```

and it works fine. I can output user data on my view.

I have created a model called students which holds students data with user_id which is coming from user table. Like  1->N relationship. A user has multiple students associated with it. How can I call custom model in my view.

Answer (score 2):

Pass student data to view

```
$students = Student::all();

return view('student_view')
->with('student_data', $students);
```

View like this in table

```
<table id="table-student" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="5%" class="text-center">No.</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($student_data as $student)
      <tr>
        <td width="5%"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->description }}</td>       
      </tr> 
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable and pass it to the view:

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->with('students')->first();

return view('some.view', compact('user'));
```

Then you can itearte over students in the view:

```
@foreach ($user->students as $student)
    {{ $student->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view your can directly call the relation method as:

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->students as $student)
  {{ $student->name }}
@endforeach
```

*Assuming your relation method name is `students`.*